Enum value expectation using Swift Testing
I have an enum:
enum State: Equatable {
    case .active
    case .paused(for: TimeInterval)
}

I can write a clean, readable expectation that matches the enum case that has no associated values:
#expect(newState == .active)

For a case with an associated value, I can perform a full equality check like this:
#expect(newState == .paused(for: 42.1))

But for a case with associated values, an equality check on only identity is not possible:
// ERROR: Member 'paused(for:)' expects argument of type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')
#expect(newState == .paused)

// ERROR: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'State' and '(TimeInterval) -> State' (aka '(Double) -> State')
#expect(newState == State.paused)

// A complete syntax failure:
#expect(newState == case State.paused)
#expect(newState is case State.paused)

In a non-expectation, I can use a case pattern match, something like
if case .paused(_) = newState { /* do something */ }

But there's no clean way to negate that, so in Swift Testing it ends up being something like this:
if case .paused(_) = newState {} else {
    Issue.record("newState → \(newState) not .paused")
}

// or

switch newState {
    case .paused(_):
        break
    default:
        Issue.record("newState → \(newState) not .paused")
}

which are both not very readable. And the message passed to Issue.record is something that has to be rewritten for every assertion, which is likely to be missed and record a misleading message.
When I need to assert expectations on an associated value in the enum, the pattern gets worse. In this case, I need to check the value of the TimeInterval value with a certain amount of tolerance, and this seems to be the only construction:
if case .paused(for: let elapsed) = newState {
    #expect(elapsed.isAlmostEqual(to: 77.1))
} else {
    Issue.record("newState → \(newState) not .paused")
}

None of these sit right with me: the flow is upside-down, making it harder to follow, and it requires me to write a customized, specific error message in my call to Issue.record instead of allowing the framework to do it for me like it does with #expect. Is there a cleaner, more Swift Testing-way to do an equality check on enum cases?
For example, in RSpec, the expectation would be something like the following (though it's obviously contrived since Ruby doesn't have an Enum type or associated values):
expect(new_state).to be_enum_of_type(State.paused)
  .with_values(for: a_value_within(0.001).of(77.1))

This is more readable and idiomatic. I want to be able to do something more similar to this with Swift Testing.

Actually #expect i am not aware ? expectation syntax is something different like     let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "test") right ?

@Shivbaba'sson Swift Testing is a new unit testing framework, currently in beta.

I ran into the same issue trying to validate Result types from a function. There's a related discussion in the Swift forums but it does not reach a satisfying conclusion.

It's a general limitation that if and switch expressions can only be used in certain contexts right now. As the error message says, the allowed contexts are return, throw, and variable assignments.

I ended taking the approach similar to what you described:
if case .failure(ImportError.unsupportedType) = result {} else {
    Issue.record("Unexpected result: \(result)")
}

... which is maybe annoying, but not terrible.
